# Why doesn’t FloatField accept to input float value?

Tags: django

I’ve built a web app with Django. Although the FloatField was designated as ‘weight’ & ‘height’ model fields, my application refused to input the float value, and only accepts integer. I attempt to declare the `FloatField` at the forms, but it doesn’t seem to work. I have no idea what’s cause and desire to know how to be able to input the float value with solving this problem.
Following is my code and Django is version 2.0

```
# Model.py
class Profile(models.Model):

    class Meta(object):
        db_table='profile'

    user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                          primary_key=True)
    weight=models.FloatField(_('weight'),blank=False)
    height=models.FloatField(_('height'),blank=False)
    bmi=models.FloatField(_('BMI'))


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.nickname


# Form.py
class BioRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields=('weight','height')
        help_texts={'weight':('Kg単位で入力してください'),'height':('cm単位で入力して下さい')}

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['weight'].widget.attrs={'placeholder':'Weight','required':True}
        self.fields['height'].widget.attrs={'placeholder':'Height','required':True}

    def clean_hight(self):
        value=self.cleaned_data.get('height')
        if value<50:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Type in with 「cm」')
        return value

# View.py
class BioRegisterView(CreateView):
    model=Profile
    template_name='mysite/bioregister.html'
    form_class=BioRegisterForm
    success_url=reverse_lazy('mysite/profile.html')
```

and the following is the bioregister.html, page in question

```
<form method='post' action="">
{% for field in form %}
<div>
    <div class='entry'>
        {{field}}
    </div>
    {%if field.errors %}
    <p> {{field.errors.0}}</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{%  endfor %}
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Register" class='bottun2'>
</form>
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to pass default argument.try this.  weight=models.FloatField(_('weight'),default=value)
height=models.FloatField(_('height'),default=value)

Comment: Thank @ Dinesh. I attempt set the default value, for example 65.5 into the weight field and the webpage actually displayed 65.5 as default value. What’s more it could accept the value of ◯◯.5, for example 64.5, 47.5 or 78.5, but unfortunately turned down input the value other than ◯◯.5 for example 64.3, 47.3 or 78.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#floatfield):

> The default form widget for this field is a NumberInput when localize
>   is False or TextInput otherwise.

As you are asking about the spinners in your widget: This is just the way your browsers renders a `NumberInput.` You can make them invisible using css.

However, for the `NumberInput` to accept any decimal value the step attribute of the input must be set to 'any'. This is waht django normally does when creating the widget for a `FloatField`.

But you are manually setting the attributes of your widget and your are setting no step attribute. I believe the default value if no stap value is provided is 1, meaning you can only enter integers.

I would recommend setting your attributes as follows in order to overcome this issue:

```
self.fields['weight'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder':'Height','required':True})
```

This way you do not miss anything important django sets by default.

Some additional information:

`widget.attrs` is a `dict` with the attributes django is using to render the widget on the html page. For some widgets django already creates attributes when creating the field. So in your case after the call `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` the attrs of the float input widget is this `dict`: `{'step': 'any'}`.

Now with your original line `self.fields['weight'].widget.attrs={'placeholder':'Weight','required':True}` your are resetting the attrs dict to `{'placeholder':'Weight','required':True}`, meaning your attrs does not have a 'step' key anymore. The default behaviour of a `NumberInput` without a 'step' attribute is to accept integers only.

So when you update the attrs `dict` (as shown above) instead of replacing it you make sure that the values in the `dict` which django has already set and which you do not want to change are left untouched and the attributes you want to add/change are put into the existing `dict`.

Comment: Thank @chris for providing advisable information. Your answer was just right, solving my trouble. On the other hand, a question raised. That are why does your suggestion (setting ‘.update()’) make the input of float accept, and what’s real cause of the rejection? As far as my poor knowledge,  the attribute (.update()) can change  something…(right?), it mean this alter ‘NumberInput’ too ‘TextInput’? I’m glad if you would provide something of clear answer 
Thank you

Comment: @GenzoIto Was a pleasure! I added some background information to my answer

Comment: Thanks. Your additional explanation made me so clear, and I got !